# Top edges have incorrect color when following guide

Tags: rubiks-cube

I’m using an official Rubik's cube guide, but sometimes in the final stage, I get the following configuration that I cannot get rid of using only the algos in the guide:

[image: configuration]

Top edges have different colors on all four sides, everything else is OK.

On which stage am I doing something wrong?

Comment: So the rear two faces also look the same as this, i.e. the other two yellow edges are also swapped? If so, there's nothing wrong, and this case should have been listed in your guide as well. What guide are you using?

Comment: Yes, rear two edges are also swapped. I’m using the guide from this page: https://www.rubiks.com/solve-it, and there is an instruction for this case, but when I follow it, it just goes to a diagonal configuration and then back to this again 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are following the official guide on [Rubiks.com](https://www.rubiks.com/solve-it), it only uses a single move sequence `F2 U L R' F2 L' R U F2` to cycle around three edges, all but the rear edge.

It says:

> Hold your Rubik’s Cube so the
> one face that is a solid color
> is the BACK, and the Yellow
> face is the UP (U) face.
>
> If no face is a solid color, it
> doesn’t matter which face is
> in the back.

You have to do the above each time before you apply the move sequence. After you apply it the first time, one of the edges will become solved, so hold the cube with that edge at the back, and apply the move sequence again. You may have to apply it a third time before it is solved.